# Install Gitlab on Cubietruck Lubuntu: rake aborted! cannot load such file -- rack/mount

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to install Gitlab on my ARM device. Therefore i followed the [installation guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md). After getting an error with "therubyracer" i compiled libv8 and installed it manually. Then i was able to install therubyracer (manually,too). After removing therubyracer from the gemfile the bundle installation succeeded.

But when running the next command of the "Initialize Database and Activate Advanced Features" I'm getting a strange error:

```
root@cubietruck:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rack/mount
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

My contains:

```
#
# PRODUCTION
#
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 5
  username: git
  password: "the password I set in step 5. Database"
  # host: localhost
  # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

running:

```
root@cubietruck:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle show rack
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2
```

Do you have any idea what to do?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the above command you wrote `RAILS_ENV=development`. I guess you meant production.

An interesting post about GitLab on arm https://rainveiltech.com/posts/gitlab-6-3-with-apache-and-passenger-on-an-arm

Comment: your are right.. i meant production (tried development setting, too. same error) .. i corrected to post

I'm using nginx instead of apache. I also tried to use Node.js instead of libv8 and therubyracer but this leads exactly to same problem :/